# python regular expression regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all the vowels from the string.
but the following code doesn't work.
Instead I need to put escape character before ^
i.e  `obj=re.compile(r'[\^aeiouAEIOU]')`

```
import re

def disemvowel(string):
    obj=re.compile(r'[^aeiouAEIOU]')   
    k=obj.sub('',string)
    return k

s='This website is for losers LOL!'  
print( disemvowel(s) )
```

Comment: You actually want to remove vowels, so `obj=re.compile(r'[aeiou]', re.I)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove vowels, you match all the vowels from your string and replace it by `''`, so, there is no need to add `^` inside `[]`:

```
import re

def disemvowel(string):
    obj=re.compile(r'[aeiou]', re.I)   
    k=obj.sub('',string)
    return k

s='This website is for losers LOL!'  
print(disemvowel(s))
# Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually your current character class `[^aeiouAEIOU]` will match everything *except* for vowels.  Try this version:

```
s = "This website is for losers LOL!"
out = re.sub(r'[aeiou]', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(s + "\n" + out)
```

This prints:

```
This website is for losers LOL!
Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is :

```
import re

string = "This website is for losers LOL!"
print(re.sub("[aeiouAEIOU]","",string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def rem_vowel(string):
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for x in string.lower():
        if x in vowels:
            string = string.replace(x, "")

    print(string)

string = "This website is for losers LOL!"
rem_vowel(string)
```